# Bashscript throws command error when populating variable

Tags: linux, bash

i have the following two lines in a batch script

```
iperf_options=" -O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P " $streams
$iperf_options=$iperf_options $proto
```

and

```
$streams = 2
$proto = -u
```

but when i run this i get the following error.

./bandwidth: line 116: -O: command not found

I am simply trying to wrote a string and then append it to a variable so why does it throw the error on the -O?

I have looked about the web but i jsut seem to find stuff about spaces around the "="

any help greatfully recived.

Thankyou

code block to show error

```
proto=-u
streams=2
iperf_options=" -O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P " $streams
$iperf_options=$iperf_options $proto
```

running this will give this out put

```
./test
./test: line 3: 2: command not found
./test: line 4: =: command not found
```

Comment: sorry, but neither the variable assignments nor the error message look anything like `batch-file`. Did you mean `bash`?

Comment: Neither of your two lines are commands understood by the command interpreter on MS-DOS, IBM OS/2, or Microsoft Windows systems. Did you make any attempt at reading the description for the [[tag:batch-file]] tag, before assigning it to your question?

Comment: Sorry that me being stupid you are right i meant to type bash.

Comment: in bash you have to omit space between variable and value, it means instead of `a = 110` you have to write `a=110` another thing is, when you wanna declare a variable you don't have to use `$` but when you call it you have, for example `a=110` and call it like this `echo $a`, good luck !

Comment: so freeman in the above there is no space. or is it the space with in the string " -O... considered a space. as it lets me decare it with it. its the $iperf_options=$iperf_options... that is causign the issue

Comment: may I see your whole code ?

Comment: proto = -u   
streams = 2  

iperf_options=" -O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P " $streams   
$iperf_options=$iperf_options $proto

Comment: No, we need more than that.

Comment: No Ben those 4 lines will throw the error "proto=-u", "streams=2" folowed by the two lines in the original post

Comment: Added the snip above that you can run to test asa bash script

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) re: why string-type variables should not be used to store commands, and what to do instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main mistakes here, in a variety of combinations.

1. Use `$` to *get* the value of a variable, never when *setting* the variable (or changing its properties):

   ```
   $var=value    # Bad
   var=value     # Good
   var=$othervar # Also good
   ```
2. Spaces are critical delimiters in shell syntax; adding (or removing) them can change the meaning of a command in unexpected ways:

   ```
   var = value    # Runs `var` as a command, passing "=" and "value" as arguments
   var=val1 val2  # Runs `val2` as a command, with var=val1 set in its environment

   var="val1 val2"  # Sets `var1` to `val1 val2`
   ```

   So, in this command:

   ```
   iperf_options=" -O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P " $streams
   ```

   The space between `iperf_options="..."` and `$streams` means that it'll expand `$streams` *and try to run it as a command* (with `iperf_options` set in its environment). You want something like:

   ```
   iperf_options=" -O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P $streams"
   ```

   Here, since `$streams` is part of the double-quoted string, it'll be expanded (variable expand inside double-quotes, but not in single-quoted), and its value included in the value assigned to `iperf_options`.

There's actually a third mistake (or at least dubious scripting practice): building lists of options as simple string variables. This works in simple cases, but [fails when things get complex](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/432352/list-of-arguments-in-only-one-variable-in-bash). If you're using a shell that supports arrays (e.g. bash, ksh, zsh, etc, but not dash), it's better to use those instead, and store each option/argument as a separate array element, and then expand the array with `"${arrayname[@]}"` to get all of the elements out intact (yes, all those quotes, braces, brackets, etc are actually needed).

```
proto="-u"    # If this'll always have exactly one value, plain string is ok
streams=2     # Same here
iperf_options=(-O 10 -V -i 10 --get-server-output -P "$streams")
iperf_options=("${iperf_options[@]}" "$proto")
# ...
iperf "${iperf_options[@]}"
```

Finally, I recommend [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) to sanity-check your scripts for common mistakes. A warning, though: it won't catch all errors, since it doesn't know your intent. For instance, if it sees `var=val1 val2` it'll assume you *meant* to run `val2` as a command and won't flag it as a mistake.

Comment: Ahh right, thank you. I understood the space between the var=value must not exist, but i can see it was after the quoted string i was adding one as well.

Comment: Oh and thanks for the headup about the site to check it, it will be added to the bookmarks next to the regex checker :)

Comment: to check changed it to iperf_options=" -O 10.... $streams $proto" but will swap to an array later. Thanks for taking the time to answer this and for the detailed explication.

Comment: @DevilWAH That'll work as long as none of the options/arguments you're storing contain whitespace, wildcards, quotes, escapes, etc -- basically as long as they're just straight plaintext with no shell syntax separated by spaces, you can get away with using a plain string.